# Comma is generating separate rows for a particular value in a column while exporting table from pyspark cluster to BigQuery

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I was exporting a spark df to bigquery by using the code below

```
gcs_bucket = 'main'
bq_dataset = 'table'
bq_table = 'user'

Rules.write \
  .format("bigquery") \
  .option("table","{}.{}".format(bq_dataset, bq_table)) \
  .option("temporaryGcsBucket", gcs_bucket) \
  .mode('overwrite') \
  .save()
```

Below is the output i was getting within the cluster

```
+-----------+----------+-------------------+------------------+
| antecedent|consequent|         confidence|              lift|
+-----------+----------+-------------------+------------------+
|[19, 6, 39]|      [44]|  0.418945963975984|10.602038775664845|
|[19, 6, 39]|      [35]|0.47298198799199465| 7.423073393311932|
|[19, 6, 39]|     [322]|   0.47631754503002|4.6520592549063995|
|[19, 6, 39]|     [308]| 0.4496330887258172| 5.856259667533207|
|[19, 6, 39]|     [345]| 0.5196797865243495|5.4970336458402285|
```

when exported the above df to bigquery, i am getting the table in the below format. Why is that? and how can i fix it?

[image]

Comment: this is how BigQuery UI visualize arrays (repeated fields)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your output, it seems that `antecedent` and `consequent` are arrays or python lists. These are converted to [BigQuery's arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#array_type).

Comment: Got it! Thanks. Is there a way i can club the array values into one row?

Answer (score 1):

This is how BigQuery UI visualize arrays (repeated fields)!
In both Classic and Console UI

[image]

Meantime, this is just matter of how given Tool represents / visualize certain data types

For example, in Goliath (part of Potens.io Suite) same will be represented as

[image]

with ability then to drill down to specific data cell and see it as (for example)

[image]

Comment: Got it, Thanks! Is there a way i can keep it in the same format in bigquery?

Comment: if you have array of strings - you can use ARRAY_TO_STRING function. in case of not string - integers for example - you can use following approach - just an example of approach -  `SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(el AS STRING)) FROM UNNEST([19, 6, 39]) AS el`

Comment: Return this error: ```Error: Cannot access field element on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<element STRING>>```

Comment: sure. if you have struct you need to add some more coding  - feel free to post new question with all relevant details - for us to be able to help you!